# Behat 3: How to make an object initialized in @BeforeSuite hook available inside the Scenario / Context scope?

Tags: scope, behat

I have a Behat FeatureContext with some custom steps, and I'd like to do the following:

- Initialize a variable/array/object when the test suite starts,
- Have that variable/array/object available within the scope of each Scenario in the test suite,
- Have values stored in the variable/array/object updated after all of the steps in each Scenario execute,
- When test suite execution is complete, persist the values (writing out to a log file would be perfect).

Can this be done, and how would you go about structuring this?  I'm attempting to do this using @BeforeSuite, @BeforeScenario and @AfterScenario hooks but have not yet been successful (my OOP is a little rusty).

Comment: You should try to use page objects, some variables might belong in a page objects, some maybe in a general class that you use to generate data to be used and some might come from config yml file. You should split this question in multiple question with specific issues and it will be a + if you could add some code what you have tried. For page objects you can check http://behat-page-object-extension.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/introduction.html

Comment: @Lisa Ridley Your requirements seem very simple to accomplish. If you search for `BeforeScenario` keyword in http://www.inanzzz.com/ , you'll see examples. However 1, apart from the 1st point, the rest is not good practise. A scenario's behaviour depending on another scenario's behaviour is not a good practise. They all should be isolated so you'll have to refactor your logic. However 2, some people don't care about it and go ahead with bad practise.